# Context is closed when EF tries to access null property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an object defined by my entity framework model that has navigation properties, but whenever the navigation property is null, entity framework seems to try to pull it down again from the database. This is fine for now and I can work on this problem later, but when it tries to get the navigation property from the database, I get the error from the model:

The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Well this isn't too good that it's blowing chunks like this. Is there anything I can do to ensure that this is only attempted when the context is still open?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lazy loading turned on, but you've disposed your `ObjectContext`. Either don't dispose it so soon or [turn off lazy loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I wish I could keep the context open. However, design choices that I have no control over won't allow the context to remain open. The other issue is not that it is lazy loaded either, since it has attempted to load the navigation property using the non-null Id in the model, but the record doesn't exist giving me a null navigation property. This is fine for when the context is open, but on subsequent accesses, the framework tries to get the property again, only with the context closed. cont...

Comment: I would put a FK constraint on it to keep this whole issue from happening in the first place, but the objects are coming from a view which contains columns from tables in another db. Any other thoughts?

Comment: The framework won't "try to get the property again" if you turn lazy loading off.

Answer (score 1):

EF framework also supports 'eager loading'. This means that the related entities will be returned in the same query. For this of course you have to know in advance which related entities you need, but this is a technique I use a lot.
It might be worth giving it a shot in your scenario.

Here is same sample code of MSDN: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx)

```
// Define a LINQ query with a path that returns 
// orders and items for a contact.
var contacts = (from contact in context.Contacts
              .Include("SalesOrderHeaders.SalesOrderDetails")
                select contact).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Eager loading won't fix his problem, unless you eager load every possible association, with infinite depth.